# Tensorflow DNNClassifier unittest features

Tags: python, unit-testing, tensorflow

I am creating a `DNNClassifier` in a method that returns the classifier. I want to write a unit test to verify that the list of features passed is the one that is expected. However, since the features are not an attribute of `DNNClassifier`, I don't know how to get the list of features from the classifier.

Some code to illustrate the point.

```
def create_dnn_classifier(features, config, directory):
    # some manipulation on features
    classifier = DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=features, # list of tf.feature_column.numeric_column
        hidden_units=[512, 256, 128],
        activation_fn=tf.nn.leaky_relu,
        dropout=0.1,
        n_classes=2,
        config=config,
        model_dir=directory)
    return classifier
```

Unittest look like this.

```
class TestMyDNNClassifierFeatures(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_classifier_features(self):
        classifier = create_dnn_classifier(
            ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3'],
            RunConfig(
                save_checkpoints_steps=100,
                keep_checkpoint_max=100,
                keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=None,
                model_dir='test_dir'
            ),
            'test_dir'
        )
        # how do i get the list of features from classifer now?
        print classifier.features # won't work as classifier has no attribute named features
        print dir(classifier) # prints a lot of things but none resembling features
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier` object doesn't store the features names inside the object state. Therefore, you can't retrieve them. However, you can make a convenience wrapper like:

```
class DNNWrapper:

    def __init__(self, features, config, directory):
        self.features = features
        self.classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
            feature_columns=features,
            hidden_units=[512, 256, 128],
            activation_fn=tf.nn.leaky_relu,
            dropout=0.1,
            n_classes=2,
            config=config,
            model_dir=directory)
```

And then, instead of testing the `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier`, just test your wrapper `DNNWrapper`:

```
class TestMyDNNClassifierFeatures(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_classifier_features(self):
        classifier = DNNWrapper(
            ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3'],
            tf.Estimator.RunConfig(
                save_checkpoints_steps=100,
                keep_checkpoint_max=100,
                keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=None,
                model_dir='test_dir'
            ),
            'test_dir'
        )
        print(classifier.features)
```